# Visual Studio 2022 build tools

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I need to silently install Visual Studio 2022 C++ build tools using a script. The script should download an offline installer and install it on a machine. Visual studio 2022 does not provide offline installer, but it can be created using [Create an offline installation document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). Following this document for C++ development it suggests to create a local layout with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop` workload. The resulting offline installer is about 3GB which is fine. From the script the offline installer is called with `C:\CppBuildTools\vs_setup.exe --quiet --nocache --wait --in C:\CppBuildTools\CustomInstall.json` command and the bellow is the content of `CustomInstall.json` file.

```
{
    "installChannelUri": ".\\ChannelManifest.json",
    "channelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel",
    "installCatalogUri": ".\\Catalog.json",
    "channelId": "VisualStudio.17.Release",
    "productId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community",
  
    "includeRecommended": true,
    "quiet": true,
    "norestart": true,
  
    "addProductLang": [
        "en-US"
    ],
  
    "add": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC"
    ]
}
```

This approach requires almost 40GB storage and installs Visual Studio 2022 IDE and a lot of component which are not required. The script is supposed to install all the required component to build a C++ project on a build machine. So I'm wondering how to create the Visual Studio 2022 offline installer and how to install C++ build tools silently without including the IDE and other non essential components?

Comment: "So I'm wondering how to create the Visual Studio 2022 offline installer" - You create the ISO that only contains the components you want to run, you do this once, then run the installer using whatever method you want to use. What might be easier is to create a [local layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#step-3---install-visual-studio-from-the-local-layout), and use that, to install what you want.

Comment: I'm having troubles skipping IDE installation. It seems no mater what components I choose, the IDE and IDE related tools are being installed.